# Django | 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-views

A la view llega password1 te un template. Tengo un token en la variable token. Se trata de que al usuario se le guarde el nuevo password1. El la view se filtra por el token y t contiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A ese user se le debe guardar el password1.

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Views.py**

...

```
t = TokenToUser.objects.filter(token=token)
u = User.objects.get(username__in=t.user)
u.password=password1
u.save()
```

...

**Models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class TokenToUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=34, null=True, blank=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                verbose_name='Registration date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Para solucionar el error

El error que muestras se debe a la consulta, no usas un token para buscar el usuario sino una colección de tokens.

```
t = TokenToUser.objects.filter(token=token)
```

debes cambiarlo por

```
t = TokenToUser.objects.get(token=token)
```

Por lógica de tu código, el campo token debería contener valores únicos (si un token estuviera duplicado no podrías estar seguro de cuál de los usuarios con ese token está haciendo la petición de cambio de password).

Una vez logrado un único valor para token, el usuario es muy simple:

```
u = t.user
```

### Para cambiar la contraseña

La función `set_password` de la clase User toma una cadena (password1 en tu caso) y la codifica para guardarla como password del usuario.

```
u.set_password(password1)
```

La [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#methods) está solo en inglés, pero puede serte de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las solución. Funciona perfecto. ; )